# Using textcomp currency symbols in siunitx column gives compilation error

Tags: tables, errors, siunitx, textcomp

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rS}
  US  & \$5.00\\
  CAN & \$6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

However, trying to compile this gives the following error:

```
! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
\__siunitx_table_column_end:n ...ne_fill_skip -#1}
                                                  \tex_kern:D \c_zero_skip \...
l.14 \end{tabu}

?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These commands are not robust/protected, so `siunitx` 'thinks' they represent expandable content. Trying to expand them is therefore leading to issues. You are probably best making them engine-robust:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\textsterling
\robustify\texteuro
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rS}
  US  & \$5.00\\
  CAN & \$6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

You likely want to robustify `\$` as well so that the interpretation of all tokens is the same, and to tell `siunitx` the spacing for the number and the pre-numeral part

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\robustify\$
\robustify\textsterling
\robustify\texteuro
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rS[table-format = 1.2, table-space-text-pre = \textsterling]}
  US  & \$5.00\\
  CAN & \$6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

---

'Hiding' the input tokens will also work at the cost of being slightly less 'pleasant' to read

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rS[table-format = 1.2, table-space-text-pre = \textsterling]}
  US  & {\$}5.00\\
  CAN & {\$}6.50\\
  UK  & {\textsterling}4.00\\
  EU  & {\texteuro}4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

This tells the package that the content is textual and thus not part of the number.

---

One might well be best using a separate column for the unit

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rl@{}S}
  US  & \$            & 5.00\\
  CAN & \$            & 6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling & 4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro     & 4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

You probably also should tell the package how many digits there are

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabu}{rl@{}S[table-format = 1.2]}
  US  & \$            & 5.00\\
  CAN & \$            & 6.50\\
  UK  & \textsterling & 4.00\\
  EU  & \texteuro     & 4.50\\
\end{tabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: While robustifying the commands `\texteuro`and `\textsterling` does get them to print out, the alignment is incorrect. Using a separate column for the currency symbols is IMO a last resort, it looks much worse. Specifying the `table-format`option causes the text to be printed incorrectly.

Comment: @KevinKeith I've extended on that a bit: a few more steps would be needed that aren't tied to the currency units _per se_.

Comment: @KevinKeith I suggested a second column as the two parts are logically separate: one column is a unit, one is a value ...